# Windows Azure Web and Mobile integration

Tags: android, sql, mobile, azure, web

I am interested in creating a website through Windows Azure Web. It will be connected to an SQL database. Once my site is set up and running, I would like to begin developing mobile apps for iOS, Android, and Windows Phone.

Is there a suggested way to do this? I know that Windows Azure Mobile is offered. Is there a way to connect it to the same SQL database that my website is connected to?

Answer (score 0):

When you create your mobile service in the Azure portal, you can connect it to an existing SQL Azure database, but it looks like there are some schema structure requirements for existing tables to enable Azure Mobile Services to work w/ the data.

Take a look at [this blog post](http://chrisrisner.com/Connecting-an-Existing-Database-to-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services) for some ideas.